# NSMutableDictionary adding child

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

There must be some missing key element on how to take an `NSMutableDictionary` and make it a child of another `NSMutableDictionary` that I cannot seem to fathom. I've tried just about everything and I'm starting to think jumping off a bridge might solve the issue.

Current:

```
DICT:1 root
          |_main dict

DICT:2 root
          |_dict [A]
               |
               sub dict...
```

Desired:

```
DICT:1 root
         |_main dict
                   |_dict [A]
                        |
                        sub dict....
```

Anytime I try and add the "DICT:2" to "DICT:1" it overwrites the main dict. Leaving me with:

```
DICT:1 root
          |_dict [A]
               |
               sub dict...
```

I tried many many things, including:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[myDict setObject:@"mainDict" forKey:@"mainDict"];
[myDict setObject:@"dictA" forKey:@"mainDict"];
```

also tried:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[myDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictA];

NSMutableDictionary *moarDict = [myDict objectForKey:@"mainDict"];
[moarDict addEntriesFromDictionary:dictA];
```

and :

```
moarDict = [dictA mutableCopy];
```

ugh! `NSMutableDictionary` must hate me, because without a doubt I hate it.

Comment: There is no secret.  An NSMutableDictionary is an Objective-C object and can be inserted into another dictionary or array just like any other object.

Comment: `[myDict setObject:@"mainDict" forKey:@"mainDict"];[myDict setObject:@"dictA" forKey:@"mainDict"];` is setting the entry "mainDict" in myDict to point to the string `@"mainDict"`, and then immediately overwriting that with the string `@"dictA".  There isn't even a second dictionary in the picture, just strings.

Comment: Your first attempt probably put you on a completely wrong track. @"dictA" is an NSString* containing the string "dictA". So the second setObject statement stores a string with contents "dictA" under the key "mainDict". You probably wanted to store the objects mainDict or dictA.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[myDict setObject:mainDict forKey:@"mainDict"];
[myDict[@"mainDict"] setObject:dictA" forKey:@"dictA"];
```

This results in

```
myDict
    | mainDict
            | dictA
                 | sub dict
```